# How to delay the .trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Id like to delay the the .trigger(click) event found in the if statement of this code by 5 seconds i have tried .delay() but this has not helped me. anyone can help me with delaying this event:

```
(document).ready(function () {
                var test = $("[id$=Hidden_Results]").val();
                var data = JSON.parse(test);
                if (data.level == 2 && data.roundCounter == 1) {

                    $(".hidden_ResultValues").fancybox().trigger('click');
                }
            });
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp Should explain how to call a function after a set amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delay` only works on subsequent items in the queqe. And your code does not qualify respecting to it.

Use `setTimeout` instead.

```
$(".hidden_ResultValues").fancybox();

setTimeout(function() {
   $(".hidden_ResultValues").trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali . Glad to have helped :)